# Understanding scanf

Tags: c, scanf

i have looked through other scanf posts but i cant seem to find the issue i have here with this short code.
The thing is when i enter a b or c, it doesnt go to the if or else if statements, i cant really figure out how to fix it, any help would be lovely! thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{

char bogstav, a, b, c;

printf("Indtast a b eller c\n");
scanf("%c", &bogstav);

    if(bogstav == a)
    {
    printf("Du valgte a");
    }
        else if(bogstav == b)
        {
        printf("Du valgte b");
        }
            else if(bogstav == c)
            {
            printf("Du valgte c");
            }
                else
                {
                printf("Du valgte ikke a b eller c!");
                }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf` is very dangerous, because there is no way to handle malformed input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you want to compare bogstav to the value of the c character, not of the c value, but you're doing it in the other way :P

Just do if ( bogstav == 'b' ) to check if bogstav is equal to the b characcter.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{

char bogstav;

printf("Indtast a b eller c\n");
scanf("%c", &bogstav);

    if(bogstav == 'a')
    {
    printf("Du valgte a");
    }
        else if(bogstav == 'b')
        {
        printf("Du valgte b");
        }
            else if(bogstav == 'c')
            {
            printf("Du valgte c");
            }
                else
                {
                printf("Du valgte ikke a b eller c!");
                }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize your variables `a`, `b` and `c`.

Comment: dumb question here i guess, but dont the one i use get initialized when i use the scanf?

Comment: @MichaelJensen You only scan into `bogstav`, the others remain uninitialised.

Comment: @MichaelJensen With your `scanf`, you are setting the value of `bogstav`, not `a`, `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting those to be literal characters?

```
if(bogstav == 'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

`a`, `b` and `c` in the `if` statements are not characters, they are variables, which have not been initialized.  You want to compare to `'a'`, etc.   Or do `char a = 'a';`... , but that's probably overkill.

Answer (score 0):

two ways you can do it by declaring varriable

```
char a='a',b='b',c='c';
```

or

without declaring varriable check directly in condition like below

```
if(bogstav == 'a')
{ // do your stuff }
```